# Feature binarization for RF/GBMs?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, boosting, feature-engineering

Are there any advantages to feature binarization for random forests or gradient-boosted machines?

For example, suppose I am predicting snowstorms for the next day using various past measurements - temperature, wind speed etc. And I have a strong prior that snowstorms never lag 50 deg F or greater weather, is there any possible advantage to binarizing temperature into >50 deg F and <=50 deg F?

If yes, are there any theoretical approaches or exploratory heuristics I can use to decide if it is worth binarizing a feature?

Comment: Advantages: speed. Exploratory heuristics? Testing many models with various scenarios and evaluating lift.

Answer (score 0):

There are benefits, if you are drawing from domain knowledge, but there can be serious risks.

I would use something like Boruta/permutation-importance, making sure that the package used was something like Ranger that has the bias-fix for random forest variable importance.  Variables with many discrete levels are falsely estimated as being more important, but there is a fix.  The false, and the fix, are an example of the nature of the risk, and a way to engage that risk.